# frm-41213 cannot connect to Report server 12 c from oracle Form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

--- Print Code in oracle form after Push button Pressed

```
PROCEDURE PRINT_1 IS
  report_id REPORT_OBJECT; 
  ReportServerJob VARCHAR2(254); 
BEGIN 
  report_id := find_report_object('REPORT191');  ---Reportobejct with set .rdf path
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS); 
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE); 
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id, REPORT_DESFORMAT, 'PDF'); 
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER,'localhost:9002/reports/rwservlet?'); 
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_OTHER,'transaction.tran_id='|| :TRANS_CUST.tran_id || ' paramform=no'); 
  ReportServerJob := run_report_object(report_id); 
END;
```

-- http://localhost:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=webstart  (localhost Url)

--In report Builder the preview of myreport is ok but when call from oracle form 12 c its show me subject error.

Call oracle reports from oracle form with one parameter

Comment: In the future, please to include the full product version.   
Verify that your installation/configuration is complete.  Specifically, be sure you have COMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH.

Comment: COMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\ReportsToolsComponent\RepTools1

Comment: when i check the report running status via URL (http://localhost:9002/reports/rwservlet/showjobs?) it gives me  error (REP-52266: The in-process Reports Server rep_wls_reports_desktop-500iar7 failed to start.oracle.reports.RWException: IDL:oracle/reports/RWException:1.0
)